# Scheme: use function result as argument in same function

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I want to make a recursive scheme function that uses a its result as an argument for itself. So basically, I want get-successor to iterate a number of times, each time replacing x with the result of the previous iteration of get-successor. The function sub-list that is referenced just selects a sub-list from lst. I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now so any help is appreciated!

```
(define (get-successor lst x)
  (car (shuffle (cdr (sub-list lst x)))))
```

Comment: I don't understand what you really want.

Comment: The code and question doesn't make any sense, but it is perfectly normal to call itself and use the result. Many recursive fucntions does it. A requirement for it to work is that it has a base case where it does not recurse and that the recursive call is closer to the base case than its previous call. Eg. `(define (my-length lst) (if (null? lst) 0 (+ 1 (my-length (cdr lst))))` works since the recursion is done on a list that is one element smaller and eventually hits the base case that return `0`. It will return the length of the list. Edit your question with more specifics or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for a recursive function to be actually recursive it needs to...well, recurse. This is: it needs to call itself. Also, you want a base case so that your recursive function eventually stops recursing, otherwise you'll run out of memory.

I do not fully understand your requirements but I do recall doing a traverse on a list once recursively, this might help you:

```
#lang racket
(define in?
  (lambda (lst x)
    (if
     (empty? lst) #f ;If the list is empty, x is not in lst.
     (if (equal? (car lst) x) #t ;If the first element is x then x it's in lst.
         (in? (cdr lst) x) ; the first element is not x, check with the rest of the list recursively
     )
    )
)
)
```

What does this code do? It tells you wheter or not `x` is in the list `lst`. 
For this example I use tail recursion, by analyzing only the first (front/car) element of the list, if it happens to be different from `x`, then I discard this element and carry on with the rest/cdr of the list.

When will it stop? When the list is empty or when we have found `x`.

When will the list be empty? When we have traversed every element of the list. (cdr takes off the first element and returns the rest of the list)

I hope you're having a great time programming with DrRacket, it is my favorite language. If you have anymore doubts, be sure to let us know!

See you around.

Comment: a series of nested `if`s where all the answers are Booleans is equivalently and preferably written as a series of nested `or` and/or `and` forms. also, dangling closing parens are un-Lispy, without any clear reason for why should they be there.

Comment: This is the way I learned about 7 years ago, I've been out of the loop for a while. Thanks for the info, but can you provide an example?

Comment: `(and (empty? lst) (or (equal? ...) (in? ...)))`. :)

Comment: Ok, but this will fail for this exercise. Is there anywhere I can read about this style?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scheme/info. what do you mean by "fail" and "this exercise"?  it *is* an equivalent re-write of your code.